# Date issue in csv

Tags: php, date, export-to-csv

Export to csv is working. But date format is ######## for date 11/11/2014. The result is 
11 oct,14 for 11/7/2014. Error is during 2 digits for date. Could somebody solve the issue?

```
$fp = fopen('reports-export/publications_report-'.$from.'.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $header);
fputcsv($fp, array(date('M d, Y',strtotime($data_print->pfile_date))));
fclose($fp);
$file = 'reports-export/publications/publications_report-'.$from.'.csv'; 

            if (file_exists($file)) {

                //set appropriate headers
                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/csv');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
                ob_clean();
                flush();

                //read the file from disk and output the content.
                readfile($file);
```

Comment: display the date value with in double quotes.. It may help you further

Comment: Not to patronize but is it when you open excel and the column isn't wide enough?

Comment: How can i set column width?